# Необходимо разделить строку на 3 элемента массива

Tags: javascript

У меня есть input, туда вводиться текст в формате "11.12.2022, Заголовок, Участники, Описание".
Разделить строку через метод split я догадался к примеру так:

```
 const createEvent = input.value.split(',', 4);
```

Но в Описании, могут быть тоже запятые и раз лимит стоит 4, то в массив попадет не полное описание...

Пробую через регулярное выражение поработать с separator-ом, но пока ничего не получилось...

Подскажите как можно разделить строку на 4 элемента массива, указав разделитель " , ", но чтоб в четвертом элементе разделитель уже не срабатывал и брал полностью строку даже с запятыми.

P.S. Надеюсь объяснил ясно проблему и не ругайтесь, я тут первый раз. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение с regex.

Сначала создается регулярное выражение вида `^([^,]+),\s*([^,]+),\s*([^,]+),\s*(.+)` , где `^` (символ называется "карет" или "крышечка") - начало строки, далее n-ное количество одинаковых подвыражений `([^,]+),\s*` для захвата групп, размноженное  с помощью `.repeat()`, и замыкающее подвыражение `(.+)`.
Основное подвыражение `([^,]+),\s*`: в круглых скобках - то, что захватывается и потом появляется в итоговом массиве, а именно 1+ символов, не являющихся запятыми `[^,]+` (здесь, внутри квадратных скобок, роль символа карет - отрицание, т.е. "НЕ перечисленные далее символы"), которые ограничиваются запятой. Между этими подвыражениями 0+ пробельных символов `\s*`.
Замыкающее подвыражение `(.+)` - это 1+ любых символов до конца текста.
Результатом `.match()` является массив, где элементом с нулевым индексом является совпавшее выражение целиком, а элементами с 1 по n - захваченные подвыражения (которые в круглых скобках). Поскольку нам нужны только захваченные группы, то выводим срез, начиная с первого элемента `.slice(1)`.

```js
const max_groups = 3
const text = "11.12.2022, Заголовок, Участники, Описание, Расписание, Что-то еще";
createEvent = text.match("^" + "([^,]+),\\s*".repeat(max_groups) + "(.+)");
console.log(createEvent.slice(1));
```

Однострочник

```js
console.log("11.12.2022, Заголовок, Участники, Описание, Расписание, Что-то еще".match("^" + "([^,]+),\\s* ".repeat(3) + "(.+)").slice(1));
```

Comment: Алексей, а не затруднит вас подробнее объяснить как это работает, я хочу понять, и сейчас играюсь с регулярными выражениями. P.s спасибо вам за ответ все прекрасно работает:)

Comment: Попытался объяснить :) добавил в решение

Answer (score 0):

В регулярках не силён, поэтому три не очень умных варианта, но можно использовать

**Первый:**

```js
let arr = 'test,test2,test3,test4,привет,всем'.split(',');
let arr2 = [arr.shift(), arr.shift(), arr.shift(), arr.join(',')];

console.log(arr2);
```

**Второй:**

```js
let str = 'test,test2,test3,test4,привет,всем';
let commaPositions = [];
let commaCount = 0;

for (let index in str) {
    let char = str[index];
    
    if (commaCount === 3)
        break;
    
    if (char === ',') {
        commaPositions.push(+index);
        commaCount++;
    }        
}

let result = [
    str.substr(0, commaPositions[0]), 
    str.substr(commaPositions[0] + 1, commaPositions[1] - commaPositions[0]),
    str.substr(commaPositions[1] + 1, commaPositions[2] - commaPositions[1]),
    str.substr(commaPositions[2] + 1),
];
console.log(result);
```

**Третий (самый красивый):**

```js
let str = 'test,test2,test3,test4,привет,всем';
let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let commaPos = str.indexOf(',');
    result.push(str.substr(0, commaPos));
    str = str.substr(commaPos + 1);
}

result.push(str);

console.log(result);
```